# How to pass textbox value from strongly typed view(@model List<viewmodel>) to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

view

```
@model List<PMS.View_Model._ContributeViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contribute";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Partial("_Project")
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

      <table>
        <tr>
              <th>
                  <u>Current Members</u>
              </th>
          </tr>
      <tr>

          <th>
              ProjectID
          </th>
          <th>
              Name
          </th>
          <th>
              Role
          </th>
      </tr>

        @foreach(var item in Model.Where(m=>m.Status==1))
            {

          <tr>

              <td>             

                 @Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.ProjectID)

              </td>

              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.Name)
              </td>
              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(model=>item.RoleName)
              </td>
          </tr>
        } 
          <tr>
              <th>
                  <u>Invited Members</u>
              </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <th>
                  ProjectID
              </th>
              <th>
                  Name
              </th>
          </tr>
      @foreach(var item2 in Model.Where(m=>m.Status==0))
            {       
          <tr>             

              <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(model=>item2.ProjectID)
              </td>
              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(model=>item2.Name)
              </td>


              </tr>
            } 
          <tr>
              <td>
                  @Html.TextBoxFor(?)
              </td>

              <td>
                  <input type="submit" id="btnsearch" value="Search"/>

              </td>
          </tr>
    </table>

}
```

viewmodel

```
public class _ContributeViewModel
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Facebook { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Twitter { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string LinkedIn { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Github { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Photo { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Other { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        }
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Contribute(int? projectID)
        {


                PMSDBContext PMP = new PMSDBContext();

            //List<_ContributeViewModel> cvm = new List<_ContributeViewModel>();
            //    _Contribute cv=new _Contribute();
            //    cvm = cv.GetMember();
                List<_ContributeViewModel> result = new List<_ContributeViewModel>();
                result = PMP.Relations
                       .Join(PMP.Roles, a => a.RoleID,
                       b => b.RoleID,
                       (a, b) => new { Relation = a, Role = b })
                       .Join(PMP.Users,
                       a => a.Relation.UserID,
                       c => c.UserID,
                       (a, c) => new { a.Relation, a.Role, Users = c })
                       .Where(a => a.Relation.ProjectID == 1)
                       .Select(a => new _ContributeViewModel
                       {
                           ProjectID = a.Relation.ProjectID,
                           RoleName = a.Role.RoleName,
                           Name = a.Users.Name,
                           Status = a.Relation.Status,
                       }
                       ).ToList();
                 return View(result);

        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Contribute(_ContributeViewModel Model)
        {

            return View();
        }
```

Problem i am facing is that..i cant use **@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>Model.Name or Something)** to pass textbox value to controller..it is because of **List**?but if i remove **List<>**..i get problems in **foreach** loop...Should i use partial view for this textbox? or is there any better ways than using partial views?Please Suggest...

Comment: You need to use a `for` loop `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].SomeProperty)`. You model is a `List<T>` but your trying to post back a single item so you also need to change the POST method to `public ActionResult Contribute(List<_ContributeViewModel> model)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke .i tried your way and there are so many textboxes..sorry if i made wrong question..i want only one text box and want to send it's value to controller..thank you sir

Comment: One textbox for which property? - you have a collection of objects

Comment: Is this supposed to be a text box use to filter items in you collection?

Comment: @StephenMuecke one textbox for search property sir....result will display when search button is clicked..

Comment: Then why do you post back `_ContributeViewModel`? Your form should contain `@Html.TextBox("SearchText")` and the submit button (move everything else outside the form). Then change the method to `public ActionResult Contribute(string SearchText)`. In future, please only include the minimum code to describe you problem - no one want's to wade through all this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks you sir. i am new to mvc4 and i dont know what to do if some errors ocurr..sorry if my codes disturbed you..i wont do that again next time

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextBox()` this way:

```
 @{ 
   int index = 0; 
  } 
@foreach(var item2 in Model.Where(m=>m.Status==0))
{
  @Html.TextBox("Model["+index.ToString()+"].ProjectID",item2.ProjectID)
  @Html.TextBox("Model["+index.ToString()+"].Name",item2.Name)
  @{ index = index +1; } 
}
```

You may also refer to [this article](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/ASPNET-MVC-Binding-to-Listse28093Enumerables-on-POST-with-JQuery.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Simply create one new Model class, like:

```
public class _ContributeViewModel2
{
  List<PMS.View_Model._ContributeViewModel> ContributeList { get; set; }
  string SearchString { get; set; }
}
```

Pass this to your View and use like this,

```
@model _ContributeViewModel2

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contribute";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Partial("_Project")
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

      <table>
        <tr>
              <th>
                  <u>Current Members</u>
              </th>
          </tr>
      <tr>

          <th>
              ProjectID
          </th>
          <th>
              Name
          </th>
          <th>
              Role
          </th>
      </tr>

        @foreach(var item in Model.ContributeList.Where(m=>m.Status==1))
            {

          <tr>

              <td>             

                 @Html.DisplayFor(item.ProjectID)

              </td>

              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(item.Name)
              </td>
              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(item.RoleName)
              </td>
          </tr>
        } 
          <tr>
              <th>
                  <u>Invited Members</u>
              </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <th>
                  ProjectID
              </th>
              <th>
                  Name
              </th>
          </tr>
      @foreach(var item2 in Model.ContributeList.Where(m=>m.Status==0))
            {       
          <tr>             

              <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(item2.ProjectID)
              </td>
              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(item2.Name)
              </td>


              </tr>
            } 
          <tr>
              <td>
                  @Html.TextBoxFor(model=> m.SearchString)
              </td>

              <td>
                  <input type="submit" id="btnsearch" value="Search"/>

              </td>
          </tr>
    </table>

}
```

Thank you.